# Apps for ios 6 and ios 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

Im trying to update my app to have the iOS 7 UI. When i run it the way it is now, it runs nicely on iOS 6, but in iOS 7 it just push the navigation bar and everything else up, but when i edit my xib file to fix the problem, but then it doesnt run for iOS 7.

Any tips to make apps in Xcode 5 compatible with iOS 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need can be found in this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

You need to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to YES